# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.medialib.codec.jpeg.Encoder.njpeg_encode_init()J

Tags: java

Help me to solve this error.....
I do have the jars in the same deploy folder....Do not know why it is not linking....My error log is as follows...

```
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.medialib.codec.jpeg.Encoder.njpeg_encode_init()J
    at com.sun.medialib.codec.jpeg.Encoder.njpeg_encode_init(Native Method)
    at com.sun.medialib.codec.jpeg.Encoder.<init>(Encoder.java:26)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriter.<init>(CLibJPEGImageWriter.java:148)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: `com.sun.medialib.codec.jpeg.Encoder.njpeg_encode_init` is a native method. Do you have native libraries for the operating system you use in place and loaded?

Comment: Which Ide are u using? Or are u running it from command prompt?

Comment: i have loaded the native libraries for linux (libclib_jiio.so) and placed it in the folder...and i am running this from terminal.